# Netbeans 8.2 cannot create new projects

Tags: java, jdk, netbeans

I have had uncountable problems with Netbeans on Ubuntu and derivative distros.

I had downloaded and installed oracle jdk 8 and as far as I know it was set as default. After that I installed Netbeans through apt, but when I click to open it, it keeps loading modules and then the small screen disappears with no more response, as if the program had never been executed.

So I decided to uninstall everything and start all over again. This time, I followed the instructions explained here: https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-netbeans-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/ Which could be summed up in adding a ppa, downloading and setting oracle jdk 8 as default and then installing netbeans 8.2.

Everything seemed to work, Netbeans automatically detected where the default jdk was and Netbeans got to install. However, when I clicked the icon, even though it opened as expected, some options from the upper bar like debugging and all of that were missing, and if I clicked to create a new project nothing would happen. I then tried to check tools > options or something similar and again nothing happened.

I am desperately trying to get Netbeans to work, but everything I try seems to be in vain.

Below there is some possible useful information:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Edit: Following Geertjan Wielenga's advice of downloading the latest release (11.0), I executed  the binary file and, by the moment, it is working as it should. The only inconvenience is that there is no installer because all the new Apache Netbeans versions seem to be incubating, but it is not a big deal providing it works.

Comment: Go to netbeans.apache.org and use the latest release which is 11.0. Still have problems write to the mailing list as described at netbeans.apache.org.